# How can I rewrite this expression more succinctly?

Tags: php, yii2

What is a more succinct way to rewrite this expression.

```
$user = $user ? $user : Yii::$app->getUser()->identity;
```

Comment: How much more succinct can you get?

Comment: True. I just assumed there might be a better way to express it.

Comment: In PHP7 - `$user = $user ?? Yii::$app->getUser()->identity;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver you can add that as an answer. Not sure why people are down voting this. It is a logical question.

Comment: How about `$u = $u ? $u : Yii::$app->getUser()->identity;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP >= 7 you can use the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$user = $user ?? Yii::$app->getUser()->identity;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = $user ?: Yii::$app->user->identity;
```

Comment: Except Notice: `Undefined variable: user`.  Most people use the ternary in this way to check if it is set, if not you'll get this notice.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it a little shorter, you could use an or.

```
$user || $user = Yii::$app->getUser()->identity;
```

If you're using PHP 7, using the null coalescing operator as the AbraCadaver pointed out makes sense. This very thing is the main reason it exists.

But in general I would really recommend against trying to do too much "optimization" in terms of shortening your code. Clarity and readability are far more important than succinctness.

Comment: Except `Notice: Undefined variable: user`

Comment: I assumed `$user` was defined, but just may evaluate as false, considering the OP code with the ternary would get that same notice if it wasn't.

Comment: But I guess everyone knows what can happen when we "assume". ;)

Comment: I agree that is works if `$user` is being evaluated for truthy, but most people use the ternary in this way to check if it is set, if not you'll get this notice.

Comment: @Abra That's certainly true. Maybe I read too much into the absence of `isset` in the question.